# Flask API Endpoint Being Called Multiple Times

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, flask, flask-restful

I have developed a Flask API in Python and I'm experiencing an issue where a specific method X  which is calling different API inside rephrase_message, appears to be called multiple times, based on my logs, even though it's explicitly called only once in the code.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
class ChatRephrasing(Resource):
    @api.doc(body=chat_fields)
    def post(self):
        if check_user(request):
            data = request.get_json()
            logger.info("Start rephrasing")
            rephrasing = Rephrasing()
            generated = rephrasing.rephrase_message(data)

            if 'status_code' in generated.keys():
                logger.error(f"Rephrasing - {generated.get('status_code')} - {generated.get('message')}")
                return make_response(jsonify({"error": generated.get("message")}), generated.get("status_code"))

            logger.info(f"Rephrasing - 200")
            return generated
        else:
            logger.error(f"Access denied - check your API token")
            return "Access denied", 404
```

The corresponding logs look like this:

```
2023-05-30 15:51:42 INFO     DEV - Chat processing API: Start rephrasing
2023-05-30 15:51:42 INFO     DEV - Chat Rephrasing features: Start rephrasing
2023-05-30 15:51:42 INFO     DEV - Chat Rephrasing features: Start rephrasing
2023-05-30 15:51:42 INFO     DEV - OpenAI request helpers.py: Calling davinci completion
2023-05-30 15:51:42 INFO     DEV - OpenAI request helpers.py: Calling davinci completion
2023-05-30 15:51:51 INFO     DEV - Chat Rephrasing features: Message rephrased correctly
2023-05-30 15:51:51 INFO     DEV - Chat Rephrasing features: Message rephrased correctly
2023-05-30 15:51:51 INFO     DEV - Chat processing API: Rephrasing - 200
```

From the logs, it seems like rephrase_message is being called twice, as is "davinci completion". It seems like every operation is being logged twice. This behavior is unintended and seems to occur when I send requests quickly, one after another, to the API endpoint.

I've explored different possibilities like multiple instances of loggers, recursive calls in the code, Flask middleware interference, or server configuration error but I've not been able to pin down the issue yet.

Does anyone have an idea why this could be happening and how to fix it?

Already tried `debug=False or use_reloader=False.`

Comment: we need to see the code that is called by the API to have any chance to solve this, the Rephrasing() class for example. Judging by the logs the endpoint is only called once, so it doesn't seem to be anything related to Flask, but something probably in the Rephrasing class.